# jQuery Mobile: Swipe div inside virtual page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html, swipe

I have jquery mobile project. My requirement is that to swipe divs inside virtual page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="individual">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">                
       </div>           
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0px">                  
                <div id="imagediv1">

                </div>
                <div id="imagediv2">

                </div>
                <div id="imagediv3">

                </div>              
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">

        </div>  
    </div>
```

This is my jquery virtual page. I want to swipe between divs imagediv1 imagediv2 and imagediv3. How can i implement this?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing library that you could use called [Touch Slider](http://www.mobilizetoday.com/freebies/touchslider).

There are also some useful tutorials and plugins located [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/mobile/5-jquery-mobile-gallery-plugins/).

Comment: As it says Touch Slider is a free CSS accelerated jQuery plugin optimized for desktop and **mobile browsers**